# Combine multiple txts into one

Tags: terminal, command-line, text

I'm trying to combine multiple txts into a big file. I want them to be put in sequence but this seems not to work properly.

At this time I tried from the terminal:`cat *.txt >merged.txt` but this seems to concatenate the files randomly.

In my folder I have all the files named with sequential numbers (from 1.txt to 10000.txt). Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Globbing isn't random, it's [guaranteed to be alphabetical](https://serverfault.com/a/122743/181405) (a.k.a. lexicographic order according to your locale), which [is different from numeric sorting order](https://superuser.com/a/192355/156757).

You can use brace expansion for this.  Replace '10' with the number of the last file.

```
cat {1..10}.txt > merged.txt
```

This uses bash brace expansion, which you can read about at `LESS='+/Brace Expansion' man bash`.

Note that unlike file globs, the brace expansion will generate arbitrary strings which need not be existing files; in this case that means you will get errors if there are files missing from the sequence (e.g. if `7.txt` does not exist).  However, this won't affect the contents of `merged.txt` which will be produced as expected.

Comment: This is unnecessarily quadratic; `cat $(for i in {1..10}; do echo "${i}.txt"; done) >> merged.txt` is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop; you need better file globbing (like `zsh` has).

Comment: @wchargin Thanks, that’s neater, I thought `{1..10}` was a zsh thing but I should have thought about how cat’s multiple arguments are how it’s designed to be used.

Comment: @Wildcard You’re right, just noticed you’ve given an answer too, upvoted

Comment: Thanks; I've simplified the command in this answer, too, to be more idiomatic—hope you don't mind.  :)  This is how I would do it with bash; upvoted.

Comment: @Wildcard You're of course right that better globbing is superior to a for-loop; I just never thought of using brace expansion as a component to a larger word. Thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Use `zsh` with extended globs—and **enable numeric sorting of the glob expansions** with the `(n)` glob qualifier:

```
zsh -c 'cat *.txt(n) > merged.txt'
```

You can get more specific with your globs, also:

```
zsh -c 'cat <1-10000>.txt(n) > merged.txt'
```

See `man zshexpn` for full details.

Comment: If you have the `multios` option set you can skip the `cat` and just use `<*.txt(n) >merged.txt` (or `<*.txt~merged.txt(n) >merged.txt` in case it already exists)

Comment: It's highly unlikely, but what happens if the extension is a literal `.txt(n)`?

Comment: @JAB won't match.  Try it.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer could be:

```
ls | sort -n | xargs cat > merged.txt
```

<sup>On a GNU/Linux system you can do `ls -v | xargs cat > merged.txt`, but this is specific to the GNU version of `ls` and does *not* work for BSD `ls`.</sup>

Comment: -1, `ls -v` *on a Mac* does something completely different from `ls -v` on Linux.  Mac uses BSD tools and `-v` for numeric sorting of files is a feature of GNU `ls` only.  For BSD `ls`, `-v` means `Force unedited printing of non-graphic characters; this is the default when output is not to a terminal.`

Comment: My bad, I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Heads up. If the files are indeed numbered 1 - 10000 then the operating system is sorting your files in the order of the first number:
1.txt
11.txt
12.txt
...
19.txt
100.txt
...
2.txt
20.txt
21.txt

etc.

You would have to rename files as 00001, 00002 and so on.

Comment: Side question: quick way to do that? Automator? terminal?

Comment: rename *.txt 0000*.txt?

Comment: @Brandito, no such command as `rename` on a default Mac installation.  And even on Linux the command you wrote won't work; there are [different incompatible syntaxes for `rename` on different Linux distros](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238862/135943).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but as your filenames contain no whitespace or "unusual" characters, we can do this:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls +([0-9]).txt | sort -n | xargs cat > merged.txt
```

The `+([0-9])` is a bash [extended glob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) to match only one or more numbers.

With GNU `ls` (available via homebrew in the coreutils package)

```
ls -v +([0-9]).txt | xargs cat > merged.txt
```

Answer (score -4):

In command promt:

cd "path to directory" (Enter)

copy *.txt result.txt (Enter)

Comment: Not sure if that's a windows thing, but `copy` isn't even a command on macOS, and `cp` doesn't work like that. See the other answers.

Comment: What @Kevin said...I don't recall using that method to *concatenate* files in Windows so I don't know how you came about that answer.